# Issues with Django migrate on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-models

I am running (or trying) to run an app on heroku and so far it has been going well. However, now I would like to alter the table of my db and add an extra column. I did this locally by changing my django model and adding an extra column with this code:

```
 FAIRNESS = Choices("keineAngabe","Ja")
 fairness = models.CharField(choices=FAIRNESS, default="", 
 max_length=20, null=True,blank=True)
```

I ran locally then:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Pushed the whole thing to heroku and then ran

heroku python manage.py migrate

However, heroku does not seem to change its postgres db-table accordingly and I get now errors such as

```
column honoradar_datacollection.fairness does not exist
```

When I try to look into the db. Can someone tell me what kind of reset etc. might help?

Comment: Well did the heroku migrate print something on the stdout? Migrations typically are logged (you see which migrations are applied).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this line on top of the `Procfile`

> release: python manage.py migrate

And don't forget to commit the migration file before pushing to heroku.

Comment: It prints this.

remote: Running migrations:
remote:   Applying honoradar.0002_auto_20180510_1401... OK
remote:   Applying honoradar.0003_auto_20180510_1403... OK
remote:   Applying honoradar.0004_auto_20180510_1406... OK
remote:   Applying honoradar.0005_auto_20180510_1407... OK
remote: Waiting for release.... done.

However, the same error still occurs. Do I have to do something else to change the db?

Comment: @HalukaMaier-Borst is it running the respective migration file for adding `fairness` field?

Comment: Ok, weird. I reverted the website to an older git commit, than only copied the model into the folder, ran the makemigrations and migrate. Pushed it to heroku, made the migrations and then added in another commit all the other changes. Now, it is running fine. But seemingly the procfile thing helped. Thank you so much!